# Can you set off on an errand?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

This sentence is part of a somewhat formal essay I am writing. I am describing what 'He' has been up to.

> It had been ten days since **he had set off on an errand** at his manager's request and there hadn't been any updates from him until that moment.

Is the expression "set off on an errand" idiomatic? I believe its meaning is clear, but how does it sound to a native's ear?

Comment: Yep, it's fine. You can "set off on" a journey, a quest, an errand, etc.  Incidentally, did you know the *Errant* in *Knight Errant* (you know, those noble warriors forever setting off on quests and such) shares an etymology with *errand*? Has nothing to do with "being in error" (Don Quixote, the erroneous errant, notwithstanding).

Comment: Saying "He has set off..." is not idiomatic, since "set" is used to refer to an event, and "He has" is implying a state, not an event.  "He is off on an errand" would be more idiomatic, when explaining where "He" is.  "He set off on an errand" would typically be used in a narrative, to describe an event in that narrative.

Comment: @HotLicks But there is still no reason you couldn't say, in response to "Where's Jack?", "He has set off on an errand". Equally "He's off on an errand", or "He's away on an errand" would be alright too.

Comment: @HotLicks in fact it's a narrative that I am writing. I am describing what 'He' has been up to. The whole thing, if you are interested, is: 'It had been ten days since he had set off on an errand at his manager's request and there hadn't been any updates from him until that moment'.

Comment: On a side note, why has my question been downvoted? What's wrong about it?

Comment: @cldjr Not my downvote, but I think it's because the question needs [more details](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I agree with @HotLicks. Your sentence doesn't sound idiomatic and to set off on a journey sounds far more idiomatic than on an errand. The real question is why you would call his manager's request "an errand" instead of "task", "assignment" or even "mission".

Comment: Alternatively, I've heard "[set out on](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/set+out)" a lot more, which seems more idiomatic. Also, there is "se**n**t off" for tasks and errands.

Comment: @Rathony actually it's 'set off on an errand at His Majesty's request'. I am talking about a hunter who is running an errand for the king. I replaced king by manager because I was afraid it would sound, err, silly =) My gf has invited me to write with her a fantasy story to practice our English. That sentence saying 'set off on an' is part of our story.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not a native speaker. My research suggests that "had/has set off on an errand" is grammatically okay, but **it's not idiomatic**.

The only examples I found are:

1. ["Wildwood Road" By Christopher Golden](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=KEzj5A6L05IC&pg=PA303&lpg=PA303&dq=%22had%20set%20off%20on%20an%20errand%22&source=bl&ots=BsaL7SV_wI&sig=i6tzcr3xX2Ya2xOU0v54w_hOWqI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiC2vbkq7rRAhUEpI8KHR2iCTwQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22had%20set%20off%20on%20an%20errand%22&f=false)

> He was still holding her that way when the sound of an engine cut the night. Jillian had set off on an errand ... a short drive to that elegantly antique gas station, so well preserved, an echo from another era.

2. [Bernard Shandon Rodey](http://www.rodey.com/uploads/files/AboutUs/rodey_bernard_shandon_rodey.pdf)

> The defendant had set off on an errand to deposit his employer’s money at
>   the First National Bank, but had ended up gambling most of it away at “Hope’s corner faro bank” instead.

3. [Shamballa Part 3: The Philosopher's Stone](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/5832379/26/Shamballa-Part-3-The-Philosopher-s-Stone) (A fan fiction)

> My escort, Sergeant Beregond, has set off on an errand I appointed him. I already gave him instructions to meet me here.

Comment: I am not sure what the downvotes here mean. Hope somebody can help me learn.

Comment: I'm not sure either. +1 for a decent answer.

Comment: +1 from me as well - it was a decent answer indeed, thanks. Interesting examples. I had googled sentences where set off and errand showed up together but found very few usages so I was suspecting this was not so idiomatic, or at least not commonly used.